# Where is the source repository of "Ubuntu on Windows 10"?

Tags: boot, kernel, init

Although Ubuntu on Windows is still an on-going project, I think it supposed to be an open source project otherwise it will violate GPL terms.

Therefore, where is the source repository of this "subsystem" on Win10? 
I mean, the "bootloader", kernel and especially the init(1) process?

I'm hoping it's as open as possible so that anyone can contribute to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not an open source project as stated in the [GitHub repo for Bash on Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1).

You can vote for making it open source by going to the [Windows Developer Feedback site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13389537-make-windows-subsystem-for-linux-open-source). Hopefully Microsoft will listen to what the community is asking for.